# Assign User as an Administrator to a project once it is created using rest api - Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to assign a user as an administrator to a project and change the owner too via rest api in Azure DevOps. Could anyone of you point me to some documentation as how it can be done? I have looked at UserEntitlements API and Project API - but I haven't figured how I can use them for my issue. Any directions on this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assign User as an Administrator to a project once it is created using rest api - Azure DevOps

Just as you know in your previous post, we could also use the API [User Entitlements - Update User Entitlement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to assign a user as an administrator to a project:

The Request body as following:

```
[
  {"from":"",
    "op":0,
      "path":"/projectEntitlements",
        "value":{"projectRef":{"id":"<MyProjectID>"},"group":{"groupType":3}}

  }
]
```

Then I could add a user to a specific project (I am using postman):

[image]

As result, the status is 200 OK and the use is added to the project.

You can try the Request body I posted above (Replace the  to your specify project ID) and groupType is used to set different permissions:

[image]

Besides, you said you want change the owner too, do you mean change organization owner via api? If yes, I am afraid there is no such API for update the organization owner, we could only list the owner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, figured out that it can be achieved using User Entitlement API but was doubtful on how to achieve it.Thank you, it worked!

Comment: {
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "The request indicated a Content-Type of \"text/plain\" for method type \"PATCH\" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}