# Azure DevOps API to add a user or group as a admin for a team

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the API to add a user (or another group) as an admin for a team.

I am able to use the API to create a team, create groups, create areas & iterations however I can seem to add a user as an admin for the team.

Has anyone been able to do this using the API?

Comment: The [Memberships-add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) is the one you're looking for. But it needs complex steps to get subjectDescriptor and containerDescriptor before using that. So if you're trying to do sth like: Create a team=>create a group=>add members to Project Admin after that, it would be complex... Hope my answer below helps :)

Comment: Just checking in to see if this issue still blocks you, feel free to let me know if if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add member of current Organization to Project Administrator you should use:

[Memberships - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1): PUT (application/json)

`https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/memberships/{subjectDescriptor}/{containerDescriptor}?api-version=5.1-preview.1`

1.`subjectDescriptor:` A descriptor to a group or user that can be the child subject in the relationship.

2.`containerDescriptor:` A descriptor to a group that can be the container in the relationship.

**Note:**

Values of `subjectDescriptor` and `containerDescriptor` are hard to get, so I'm not sure if it meets your requirements in your specific scenario.

We have to fetch the `subjectDescriptor` (represent user) and `containerDescriptor` (represent ProjectAdmin of one project) before you use `Memberships-Add` api. For me:

I use [Users-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to list all the details about Users in Collection to get the Descriptor of one user:

[image]

And use [Groups-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to list all the groups to get the Descriptor of Project Admin of one project:

[image]

Then use `MemberShips-Add` to add the user to project RequireCheck's Project Administrator group. Once we get the 201-created, we can see the change in web portal after refreshing the page. (Sometimes it has one minute delay.)

Update: Another direction you can check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55759986/10910450).

Comment: As pointed out in the link you direct to, these descriptors are base64 values of the entities SID.
If you have retrieved a group from a project f.x., it will contain an identityUrl, GET that and you will get the groups sid, convert that to base64 and prepend with vssgp. as in image above and now you have a descriptor.
aad group? find SID, base64 and prepend with "aadgp.". you can try a manual add via their gui to fact check and see if your results match microsofts

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is now a more convenient way to add a user as project administrator using the [entitlements api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0):

- First do a request to get the Project ID: `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/projects/{projectname}?api-version=5.0`

Then use the `id` from this response to call this API:

```
POST https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.0

{
  "accessLevel": {
    "accountLicenseType": "express"
  },
  "extensions": [
    {
      "id": "ms.feed"
    }
  ],
  "user": {
    "principalName": "{user email}",
    "subjectKind": "user"
  },
  "projectEntitlements": [
    {
      "group": {
        "groupType": "ProjectAdministrator"
      },
      "projectRef": {
        "id": "{project id}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course make sure the API is called with the correct permissions.