# AzureDevops create project library

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I would like to create projects, users and so on via C#.
There is a Libary from Microsoft for adding Workitems, Comments, ... ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet)). Is there something similar for creating projects and users? I only found the documentation for the API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something simular for creating Projects and users?

You can use [ProjectHttpClient.QueueCreateProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.core.webapi.projecthttpclient.queuecreateproject?view=azure-devops-dotnet) method to create project. It comes from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.dll` which is also contained in `Azure Devops Service .net SDK`. (Just like the `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` class shared in your question)

And here's the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/5d5e23e7da54ac69d3209f3e5d1f125617dd9881/ClientLibrary/Samples/ProjectsAndTeams/ProjectsSample.cs#L120) about how to use C# client api to create project.

Comment: Is there a way to Add / Invite Users to my Project and changing their permissions?
For example with an Email

Comment: @0brine Sorry but I have no idea how to add user to one project via email... But I once answered [how to do that via Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220494/10910450). And [link1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/5d5e23e7da54ac69d3209f3e5d1f125617dd9881/ClientLibrary/Samples/Graph/MembershipSample.cs), [link2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/5d5e23e7da54ac69d3209f3e5d1f125617dd9881/ClientLibrary/Samples/Graph/UsersSample.cs) contain the corresponding C# code sample which may help. Hope it helps :)