# Creating Project in Azure DevOps using WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm writing a WebApi to create projects in Azure Devops. The creation itself already works, but is it possible to set the team and the project manager with the Api?

I didn't find a way to do this. I already tried to add the team to the request body of the creation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) but that doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, is there any update for this issue? Please let me know whether my answer helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still working on it and was instructed to take care of another problem first. I'll let you know as soon as I can continue working on this issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Hope your problem can be solved successfully!

Comment: I think I solved the problem with the project administrator, but I don't know how to get a descriptor of the team I want to set as Project Contributors.
The WebApiTeam.Identity.Descriptor.Identifier field is always null, even in the automatically created teams. I also don't know if it is even possible to use Membership - Add with a team instead of an user or a group. Do you have an idea what I can do to set a specific team as Project Contributors?

Comment: To get a descriptor of the team, you can use the REST API [Teams-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). To set a specific team as Project Contributors, you can use the REST API [Members - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). As long as the team is in the project, you can use it to add a team as a Project Contributor by replacing `{memberId}` with `{teamId}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported for setting up teams and project administrators when a project is created, but you can do these using two REST APIs after the project is created.

Azure DevOps will set a default team when you create a project. The default team will be named "{project name} Team". To create a new team, you can use the following API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams?api-version=5.1
```

Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for detailed information.

Azure DevOps sets the person who creates the project as the first administrator. To add a new administrator, you can use the following REST API

```
PUT https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/memberships/{subjectDescriptor}/{containerDescriptor}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Click [Memberships-Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for detailed information. You can refer to [this relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210895/azure-devops-api-to-add-a-user-or-group-as-a-admin-for-a-team/61220494#61220494) for the specific operation.

Comment: I don't really want to create a new team but rather use an existing team. Is there a posibility for that? I know how to get a list of all teams of the organisation and  I want to choose one of these teams for the project.

Comment: @Nok Yes, you can. Please refer to the second REST API.